# Footer overlapping only one page

Tags: php, html, css

The footer is overlapping one of my webpage. all the others pages are fine but this one its overlapping, i dont really want to edit/update the footer as it is working in other pages, but I would like to see if there is something I can do with the css container for this page.

CSS

```
#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:0.4%;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.boxChildLeft {
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

CSS footer/body etc

```
html,
body {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
#container {
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
#header {
  background:white;
  padding:10px;
}
#body {
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
  background:#EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

PHP/HTML

```
for($temp = 1; $temp <= $cArray[2]; $temp++)
{
  $img .= "<div class='boxChildLeft'>
            <div class='img'>
              <img src='../ProductImages/$cArray[0].jpg' width='100px' height='100px'>
            </div>
            <div class='prodInfo'>
                  <p1>$pName</p1><br>
                  <span id='sp'><p1>$pPrice<p1>
                  </span>
            </div>
         </div>";
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="box">
    <?php echo $img;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't really help with the current information, could you provide some of your footer code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you provided is not enough, what I suggest is to use W3school HTML [validator](https://validator.w3.org) it will indicate what's missing from your HTML implementation, it will help you by giving suggestions.